# rdkafka dotnet library slow consumer performance

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Right now I'm following the Simple/Advanced Consumer example for OnMessage event handler, and the performance is pretty poor. (120k messages per minute vs (1M messages per minute using our C++ library)

Could be latency in consuming the message by waiting for OnMessage event, rather than implementing a busy loop and using .Consume(TimeSpan)?

```
var config = new Config() { GroupId = "example-csharp-consumer" };
using (var consumer = new EventConsumer(config, "127.0.0.1:9092"))
{
    consumer.OnMessage += (obj, msg) =>
    {
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Payload, 0, msg.Payload.Length);
        Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} Offset: {msg.Offset} {text}");
    };

    consumer.Subscribe(new []{"testtopic"});
    consumer.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Started consumer, press enter to stop consuming");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What's your average message size? What is the consumer CPU usage? What is the broker(s) CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

By default, librdkafka (which rdkafka-dotnet is built on) is tuned for high throughput. If you want low latency: "Setting queue.buffering.max.ms to 1 will make sure messages are sent as soon as possible." (from: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md)

Now I re-read your question I see you're probably after throughput. Perhaps try adjusting some of the settings listed in: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

Using EventConsumer / OnMessage shouldn't be any slower than calling Consumer.Consume in a loop as this is what EventConsumer is doing internally. 
Note: I'm currently working on improving the rdkafka-dotnet API and also looking into performance - I'll post more here when I know more.